# How to make a calculator in Excel that has 3 cells, and when any 2 are filled the remaining one gets calculated?

Tags: excel

For example, a speed-distance-time calculator.

Since Distance = Speed x Time,

There are 3 cells, one each for D, S, and T.

Filling any 2 of these 3 values, the other one gets calculated automatically.

Comment: you will need vba for this.

Comment: Where are we going to fill the multiply/addition/subtraction sign?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you'll have your values in A1,B1 and C1
Maybe you can do a Macro that COUNT the values in the range (A1:C1), when the resulting count equals 2 (meaning at least two numbers were filled), you do a little math to calculate the remaining value. Maybe you'll need some If's to accomplish that.

You'll need to add another piece of code to trigger the macro automatically

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then 'add other cells here
        Call Mymacro
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First, enable the developer tab if you do not already have it.
<kbd>File</kbd>→<kbd>Options</kbd>→<kbd>Customize Ribbon</kbd>→check the box for Developer in the right panel

Second, go to the developer tab and click on the Visual Basic Button

Third, under the Microsoft Excel Objects folder in the left panel, double-click on Sheet1(Sheet1)

Fourth, in the box that pops up, paste the following code:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 Dim speed As String
 Dim time As String
 Dim distance As String
 
 speed = Range("A1").Value
 time = Range("B1").Value
 distance = Range("C1").Value
    
 If speed = "" And time <> "" And distance <> "" Then
    Range("A1").Value = Range("C1").Value / Range("B1").Value
 ElseIf speed <> "" And time = "" And distance <> "" Then
    Range("B1").Value = Range("C1").Value / Range("A1").Value
 ElseIf speed <> "" And time <> "" And distance = "" Then
    Range("C1").Value = Range("B1").Value * Range("A1").Value
 End If
End Sub
```

Fifth, click
<kbd>File</kbd>→<kbd>Close and return to Microsoft Excel</kbd>

Sixth, you may need to add the file location to your list of trusted locations
<kbd>File</kbd>→<kbd>Options</kbd>→<kbd>Trust Center</kbd>→<kbd>Trust Center Settings</kbd>→<kbd>Trusted Locations</kbd>